# Issue with asynchronous mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to loop through an array and find the amount of tickets assigned to each person.

Unfortunately, I noticed that my `taskcount` is getting the same values but in different order, because of its asynchronous nature.

Some queries might take long and so the ones that gets finished first gets inserted and hence my array has the same values but in different order. Now, I want to avoid that and make it so, that once a query gets completed, only then the next value from the array is being picked up and pushed to search from the db. How can i modify my existing code.

```
exports.find_task_count = function(callback) {    
    var names = ['Evan', 'Surajit', 'Isis', 'Millie', 'Sharon', 'Phoebe', 'Angel', 'Serah']

    var taskcount = []    
    var resultsCount = 0;    

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        _tasks.find({'assignee': names[i]}, function (err, tickets) {    
            resultsCount++

            if (err) {
                console.log(err)    
                return callback(err)
            } else {    
                taskcount.push(tickets.length)    

                if (resultsCount === names.length) {
                    return callback(taskcount);
                    taskcount=[]
                }
            }    
        })    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you use $in operator to check the array items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `async` module designed to handle such scenarios.
I have updated the code as follows

```
    var async = require('async');

exports.find_task_count = function (callback) {

  var names = ['Evan', 'Surajit', 'Isis', 'Millie', 'Sharon', 'Phoebe', 'Angel', 'Serah'];

  async.map(names, function (name, iterateeCallback) {
    _tasks.find({ 'assignee': name }, function (err, tickets) {
      if (err) {
        return iterateeCallback(err);
      }

      return iterateeCallback(null, tickets.length);
    });
  }, function (error, results) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    }

    return callback(null, results);
  });
}
```

As per the documentation of [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map)

> Note, that since this function applies the iteratee to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will complete in order. However, the results array will be in the same order as the original coll.

if you still want to process the array in series use `mapSeries` instead of `map` in the above code